# Sax parser : get tagcontent below child tag

Tags: java, sax

Is there a way to get CDATA tag content from the following xml tag (category):

```
 <category>
    <h1>Some data</h1>
    <![CDATA[<br> some data ...]]>
    <h1>Some data</h1>
    <![CDATA[<br> more data ...]]> 
</category>
```

Could somehow characters method get only content inside category tag but outside h1 tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Override `startCDATA()` and `endCDATA()` methods in [DefaultHandler2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/DefaultHandler2.html) implementation.

   ```
   DefaultHandler2 handler2 = new DefaultHandler2() { /* ... */ }
   ```
2. Configure [XMLReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html)

   ```
   SAXParser saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
   xmlReader.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", handler2);
   ```
3. Start parsing

   ```
   saxParser.parse( /* input source */, handler2);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a forgot to mention that this content is not always CDATA content. I'm also working on some legacy code and DefaultHandler is used as a content handler, could it be combined with the lexical handler?

Comment: @siki_2014 Not sure i understand the question. `DefaultHandler2` can be used in place of `DefaultHandler` and also as `LexicalHandler`. Do you mean that class is not available? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @siki_2014 Yes. `class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler implements LexicalHandler`. Implement the methods from the `LexicalHandler`. Advantage with `DefaultHandler2` is that, you don't need to implement all the methods.

Comment: yes you are right, I can implement `LexicalHandler` `stardCDATA` and `endCDATA`, but problem is, as I mentioned in the comment above, that this content appears sometimes as a text type, it is not always CDATA, is it possible with SAX parser to get all subtags as a value for example:  `<h1>Some data</h1>
    <![CDATA[<br> some data ...]]>
    <h1>Some data</h1>
    <![CDATA[<br> more data ...]]>` to be as considered as a value of the `category` tag